# Facebook offline_access expire time

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I call the endpoint:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=clientID&client_secret=secretKEY&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=VALIDACESSTOKEN

I get this answer:

`access_token=NewACCESSTOKEN&expires=6271`

What is the unit of the expire time? Seconds? Hours?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's in **seconds** before it expires.

Comment: But when I convert the expires time into a timestamp unit I got this value : Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:44:31 GMT  it seems no sense to me ...

Comment: Can you edit the question with the exact value you get from Facebook? Also, how are you converting that?

Comment: this is the exact time returned by facebook. Actually I want to make sure that the exchange endpoint works so i can start to use it the 1frist of may (the offline_access deprecation date). I also noticed that the new token returned is exactly the same token that I passed in the exchange request.

Comment: if it is in sconds that means my token will expire in less than 2  hours. Althoug in the documentation we are talking about a 60 days of life for a token! I am lost now :(

Comment: If you are using the client side authentication (Javascript SDK) you will need to extend it and then receive a 60 day token. If you are using the server side authentication (PHP SDK for instance), you will recieve the 60 day token right away. read more: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

i think it is in seconds. according to their docs it is around 60 days.
i got expiry time of 5152380. which comes out ~=60'